# how can i draw this grid shape?

Tags: tables, shapes

Hey guys im trying to form a shape of a grid with text and arrows proparly and i didnt got so far. how can i draw it ? [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you tried sofar.

Comment: There are lots of ways to to the grid and text, but the arrows generally require tikz and possibly \tikzmark.

Comment: actually i was just started using Latex few days ago and a more concrete answers or a more specific direction (where can i learn such things, what are the names or tutorials i should look for ) would be really appreciated

Answer (score 4):

To give you a start:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}     
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\draw (0,0) grid (4,3);
\node (t1) at (0.5,0.5) {text};
\draw[-latex] (t1) to[out=90,in=-180] (0.8,1.5) node[below]{text};
\draw[-latex] (t1.north east) to[out=20,in=-150] (1.2,1.5) node[below right]{text};
\draw[-latex] (t1.south east) to[out=20,in=-200] (1.5,0.5) node[below]{text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if you aim at more sophisticated schemes, you may want to load the matrix library and draw the thing as a matrix of nodes. There are also other options, and depending on what you ultimately want to do these could be more appropriate.

Comment: @Dua If that answers your question, could you perhaps consider accepting the answer by clicking the check mark left of it?